# How to read with 'File' without modifying the actual File?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Printer {
    private File f;
    private Scanner in;

    public Printer(){
        try {
            f = new File("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\num.txt");
            in = new Scanner(f);
        }catch (IOException i){
            System.out.println(i.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public double average(){
        int count = 0;
        double total = 0;
        while (in.hasNext()){
            count++;
            total += in.nextInt();
        }
        return total / count;
    }

    public void readFile(){
        while (in.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(in.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer mine = new Printer();
        System.out.println(mine.average());
        mine.readFile();
    }
}
```

Output:

`5.666666666666667`
Note: I was also expecting the print out of each single word.

How can I read from a file without modifying it? I noticed that if I do `in.nextInt();` it removes the value from the file. Furthermore when I debugged and my compiler reached `while (in.hasNext()){` it jumped right over the loop. I would appreciate if someone would show me a way to read from a file without actually modifying it. I need to use this in one of my hw assignments which states to assume that the file will only be used once however I want to make it more "dynamic" so to speak and therefore be able to preserve the file with its original content for later use.

Comment: `average()` processes the whole file; when you call `readFile()`, the file pointer is at the end of the file, so there is nothing more to read. You need to re-open the file if you want to read its contents again.

Comment: @vanza By re-open you mean `f = new File("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\num.txt");`?

Comment: Check inside the file - make sure that you really *are* modifying it. I'm pretty sure that your `mine.readFile()` call is already has your file pointer at the end of the file - you can't read anything else.

Comment: @SimionMita: no, you need to create a new `Scanner`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I read from a file without modifying it? I noticed that if I do in.nextInt(); it removes the value from the file.

You are not modifying the file.  You are changing where the Scanner points to in the file.

> while (in.hasNext()){ it jumped right over the loop.

This means there is no more words on the line.  hasNext() checks if there is another word on the line in question.

Reading the file doesn't alter it so what you are doing is already the right idea.

Once you have read the file, it doesn't know you want to start the file again. You could re-open the file from the start however ...

What your HW appears to suggest is that you save the data in say a `List<Integer>` for printing later if this is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can read file on this way:

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            line = br.readLine();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```